# how to break the string with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I need to break this type of string using javascript:

```
3a.jpg;44.jpg;45.jpg;43.jpg;3a.jpg;44.jp;45.jpg;43.jpg;
```

into this:

```
3a.jpg
44.jpg
...
```

tried something like:

```
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
console.log(text.match(regex));
arr.push(text.match(regex));
```

With this code I get something like: `3a 44 45....`

Comment: arghhhhhh.... I wish nobody invented Regex sometimes! So many people jump to that first for such simple tasks

Comment: Regex or not, there is a potential problem when the file name contains `;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var array = yourString.split(";");
```

On a side note, I firmly believe regex should generally be used a last resort option for string manipulation.

Comment: ahh so easy :) thank you...I was thinking a regex and all that "hard" stuff and then you came with this! nice

Comment: That ";" is just a regex isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split any string without even using regular expressions using the `split` function.

E.G:

`stringToSplit.split(";");`

[More information here...](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)